# Cannot create Spritefont Visual Studio 2013

Tags: visual-studio-2013, xna, spritefont

I have a question about SpriteFont in XNA 4.0 with VS 2013.
I installed XNA 4.0 from this link: https://msxna.codeplex.com/releases/view/117230

I also installed Monogames 3.2. So, the problem is, I don't have the SpriteFont in my VS :s
There is a screenshot (Yes, sorry, my VS is in french ^^):
http://snag.gy/yROn3.jpg

I probably missed something...
If someone has an idea to help me ?

In addition to that, I see the SpriteFont in my extensions of Visual Studio 2013 in "C:\Users\name\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\12.0\Extensions\bkxnrhqx.q30\ItemTemplates\CSharp"

Thank you very much for any answer :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found the problem, I just made a mistake, I choose XNA Content project, but it was Monogames Content ^^

Sorry for the mistake :)